# node.js Как реализовать последовательный запуск методов класса

Tags: node.js

```
var a = new ClassName();
a.methodOne();
a.methodTwo();
```

Например, `methodOne` выполняется какое-то время, например минута, и после его выполнения должен запускаться `methodTwo`. Как лучше это реализовать? Т.к. при такой записи `methodTwo` запускается одновременно с `methodOne`, хотя `methodTwo` должен запуститься после выполнения `methodOne`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое - колбеки.

```
function methodOne(callBack){
   // что-то делаем и вызываем колбек
   callBack();
}


function methodTwo(){
   // что-то делаем 
}

methodOne(function(){
   //вызываем methodTwo после того, как отработает methodOne
   a.methodTwo();
});
```

Этот же пример с использованием `Promise`:

```
var methodOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // что-то делаем
    // если всё хорошо, вызываем resolve(value)
    // иначе reject(error)
    resolve({status : "ok"});
    //reject({status : "error", msg : "error here"});
});

function methodTwo(){
   // что-то делаем 
}

function methodThree(){
   // обработка ошибки
}

methodOne.then(function successHandler(result) {
    // делаем что-то с результатом
    console.log(result);
    methodTwo();
}, function failureHandler(error) {
    // обрабатываем ошибку
    console.log(error);
    methodThree();
});
```

Comment: Promise по умолчанию поддерживает [chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-chaining). Особой разницы нет, но реализация будет более гибкой.

Answer (score 1):

на [bluebird promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/features.html)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var a = new ClassName();
return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(){
        return a.methodOne();
    })
    .then(function(){
        return a.methodTwo();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть Promises, AsyncJS, а так же следует узнать о существовании колбэков